# How to update Jenkins instance before testing?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, spock, jenkins-job-dsl

#### The Problem

I'm using [Jenkins Job DSL](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin) to create my jobs and testing my scripts with `Spock` and `jenkins-test-harness`.

I'm able to install new plugins with success, based on [the Gradle example](https://github.com/sheehan/job-dsl-gradle-example/), but how can I update the plugins that already are installed?

I tried to use the UpdateCenter but even using `LinkedBlockingQueue` I'm unable to force the test to wait the update process.

#### The Code

```
import groovy.io.FileType
import hudson.PluginWrapper
import hudson.model.UpdateCenter
import javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.DslScriptLoader
import javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.JobManagement
import javaposse.jobdsl.plugin.JenkinsJobManagement
import org.junit.ClassRule
import org.jvnet.hudson.test.JenkinsRule
import spock.lang.Shared
import spock.lang.Specification
import spock.lang.Unroll

import java.util.concurrent.Future
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue

/**
 * Tests that all dsl scripts in the jobs directory will compile.
 */
class JobScriptsSpec extends Specification {
    @Shared
    @ClassRule
    JenkinsRule jenkinsRule = new JenkinsRule()

    def setupSpec() {
        printPlugins()
        jenkinsRule.getInstance().getUpdateCenter().updateAllSites()
        def plugin = jenkinsRule.getInstance().getUpdateCenter().getPlugin('subversion')
        println "Wait for subversion update..."
        def queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Future<UpdateCenter>>()
        queue.add(plugin.deploy())
        queue.take()
        println "Wait Done..."
    }

    @Unroll
    void 'test script #file.name'(File file) {
        given:

        JobManagement jm = new JenkinsJobManagement(System.out, [:], new File('.'))

        when:
        new DslScriptLoader(jm).runScript(file.text)

        then:
        noExceptionThrown()

        where:
        file << jobFiles
    }

    private void printPlugins() {
        println "****** Plugins *****"
        List<PluginWrapper> plugins = jenkinsRule.getPluginManager().getPlugins()
        plugins.each { PluginWrapper plugin ->
            println "Plugin: ${plugin.getLongName()}"
        }
    }

    static List<File> getJobFiles() {
        List<File> files = []
        new File('jobs').eachFileRecurse(FileType.FILES) {
            if (it.name.endsWith('.groovy')) {
                files << it
            }
        }
        files
    }
}
```

#### Output

```
INFO: Obtained the latest update center data file for UpdateSource default
Wait for subversion update...
Jul 01, 2016 3:58:42 PM hudson.model.UpdateSite$Plugin deploy
INFO: Adding dependent install of workflow-scm-step for plugin subversion
Jul 01, 2016 3:58:42 PM hudson.model.UpdateSite$Plugin deploy
INFO: Adding dependent install of git-client for plugin workflow-scm-step
Jul 01, 2016 3:58:42 PM hudson.model.UpdateSite$Plugin deploy
INFO: Adding dependent install of workflow-step-api for plugin workflow-scm-step
Jul 01, 2016 3:58:42 PM hudson.model.UpdateSite$Plugin deploy
INFO: Adding dependent install of structs for plugin workflow-step-api
Jul 01, 2016 3:58:42 PM hudson.model.UpdateSite$Plugin deploy
INFO: Adding dependent install of mapdb-api for plugin subversion
Wait Done...
Jul 01, 2016 3:58:42 PM hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob run
INFO: Starting the installation of Git client plugin on behalf of SYSTEM
Processing provided DSL script
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add any plugins to be installed or updated to the `testPlugins` configuration in your `build.gradle` file:

```
dependencies {
  // ...
  testPlugins 'org.jenkins-ci.plugins:subversion:2.6'
  // ...
}
```

See the Job DSL wiki for details: https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/Testing-DSL-Scripts